# Alterar diretório das fotos do fileupload

Tags: php

Estou usando o [Fileupload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) para o cadastramento de fotos para um cliente meu. Está funcionando corretamente. O problema é que ele encontra-se dentro do diretório:

> http://controle.sitecliente.com.br

E quando cadastro as fotos, ele armazena no seguinte diretório:

> http://controle.sitecliente.com.br/server/php/files/

Essas fotos serão visíveis no site dele para o público e não me sinto confortável em mostrar o diretório do gerenciador nas fotos. Tem algum meio de trocar o diretório de armazenamento?

O código segue abaixo:

No arquivo uploadhender.php, próprio do uploadfile, tem esse método:

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = new \stdClass();
        $file->name = $this->get_file_name($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index, $content_range);
        $file->size = $this->fix_integer_overflow((int)$size);
        $file->type = $type;
        if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
            $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
            $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
            if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
                mkdir($upload_dir, $this->options['mkdir_mode'], true);
            }
            $file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file->name);
            $append_file = $content_range && is_file($file_path) &&
                $file->size > $this->get_file_size($file_path);
            if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
                // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
                if ($append_file) {
                    file_put_contents(
                        $file_path,
                        fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                        FILE_APPEND
                    );
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
                    $metodos = new metodos();
                    $mostrar = $metodos->cadastrarFotos($file->name);
                }
            } else {
                // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                    $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
                );
            }
            $file_size = $this->get_file_size($file_path, $append_file);
            if ($file_size === $file->size) {
                $file->url = $this->get_download_url($file->name);
                if ($this->is_valid_image_file($file_path)) {
                    $this->handle_image_file($file_path, $file);
                }
            } else {
                $file->size = $file_size;
                if (!$content_range && $this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
                    unlink($file_path);
                    $file->error = $this->get_error_message('abort');
                }
            }
            $this->set_additional_file_properties($file);
        }
        return $file;
    }
```

Incluí essa linha para chamar o meu método:

```
$metodos->cadastrarFotos($file->name);
```

Que segue abaixo:

```
public function mostrarFotos()
  {
      $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT Fotos FROM album_fotos WHERE NomeAlbum = '".$_SESSION["NomeAlbum"]."'");
      $array = array();
      while($jm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
      {
            array_push($array,$jm["Fotos"]);
      }
      return $array;
  }
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente, mas só preciso trocar o diretório onde é armazenado as fotos sem impactar na funcionalidade desse plugin.

Comment: O que tem em `get_upload_path()`? Altere a linha `$file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file->name);` para um diretório que deseja e faça o teste, exe: `$file_path = "images/{$file->name}";`

Comment: Olá NoobSaibot. Consegui resolver de outra forma. Vou colocar como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma. No arquivo **server/php/UploadHandler.php**, vá no método:

```
function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
```

e troque:

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
```

Pelo diretório desejado. Ex.:

```
'upload_dir' => '../fotos-produtos/',
'upload_url' => '../fotos-produtos/',
```